# Underscore JS Add logic in template

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am passing the below to my Underscrore template (now fieldAttr is dynamic...can have 2 attrs, 3 attrs, etc)

```
fieldAttr: {
    id: "myElmId",
    dataModelId: $(this).attr('data-model-id')
}
```

Now in my HTML template, I want to loop  and set finalAttributesString (which i'll use to set my textarea attributes)

```
<% for (var i = 0, i < fieldAttr.length; i++) { %>
    //logic to get finalAttributesString
<% } %>

<textarea <%=finalAttributesString%>></textarea>
```

So it should render as below:

```
<textarea id="myElmId" data-model-id="123"></textarea>
```

Can I do this using Underscore JS?

Comment: What's the logic to get `data-model-id` from `dataModelId`? To what other attributes should this be applied as well?

Comment: there is no such logic....if possible, i have control to pass as the exact attribute name itself...i.e. i can pass data-model-id : $(this).attr('data-model-id')

Comment: but i think, i cannot pass hyphen in the attr name directly....

Comment: Of course you can: `fieldAttr: {id: …, "data-model-id": …}`

Answer (score 1):

It much easier to do this

```
<textarea <% for(var attr in fieldAttr) { %> <%= attr %>="<%= fieldAttr[attr] %>" <% } %> 
></textarea>
```

I made a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hFm7j/113/)

Comment: Just tried that... i am getting ReferenceError: attrs is not defined

Comment: Should be `for (` **`var`** `in …` though